# Criando chaves estrangeiras por Migration - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou com problema quando tento criar chaves estrangeiras por Migration no Laravel.

Vejam minha Migration!!!

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateEmpresaUsuarioTable extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('empresa_usuario', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('id_usuario')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('id_usuario')->references('usuario')->on('id');
        $table->integer('id_empresa')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('id_empresa')->references('empresa')->on('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}


/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('empresa_usuario');
}

}
```

Executo o comando:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Dá o seguinte erro:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'catalogrep.#sql-40  
b_65' (errno: 150) (SQL: alter table `empresa_usuario` add constraint empre  
sa_usuario_id_usuario_foreign foreign key (`id_usuario`) references `id` (`  
usuario`))
```

O engraçado é que a tabela é criada, mas o relacionamento não!!! :(

Comment: verifique se na tabela usuarios o id está unsigned e é chave primaria ou se vc fez $table->inscrements('id') nela ..

Comment: Sim, está como `unsigned` e foi criada como `$table->increments('id')`

Answer (score 2):

O erro foi meu... :s

Quando criei o migration inverti os campos em references() e on()

Onde está:

```
$table->foreign('id_usuario')->references('usuario')->on('id');
```

Deveria ser:

```
$table->foreign('id_usuario')->references('id')->on('usuario');
```

Falha minha, obrigado a quem se dispôs a ajudar!!!